# How to split string from one column into two columns that match with the list?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

How to split string from one column into two columns that match EXACTLY with the list start from the right? If not match just leave it blank for model column

List to be compare `['PILOT', 'SRP637', '103', 'Mako', 'Kontiki', 'SKX007', 'Odyssey','Octo', 'Royal Oak Offshore']`

DataFrame

```
  brand
0 ARCHIMEDE PILOT
1 Seiko SRP637
2 Sinn 103
3 Orient Mako
4 Eterna Kontiki
5 Seiko SKX007
6 Boldr Odyssey
7 Bvlgari Octo
8 Aegir
9 Audemars Piguet Royal Oak Offshore
```

Split into this data frame

```
  brand           model
0 ARCHIMEDE       PILOT
1 Seiko           SRP637
2 Sinn            103
3 Orient          Mako
4 Eterna          Kontiki
5 Seiko           SKX007
6 Boldr           Odyssey
7 Bvlgari         Octo
8 Aegir
9 Audemars Piguet Royal Oak Offshore
```

Comment: Can you also add some examples where it doesn't match exactly- what's then? I mean for now it looks like ```df.brand.str.split(" ").apply(pd.Series)```

Comment: sorry, I already updated my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## MCVE

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

textfile = StringIO("""
   brand
0  ARCHIMEDE PILOT
1  Seiko SRP637
2  Sinn 103
3  Orient Mako
4  Eterna Kontiki
5  Seiko SKX007
6  Boldr Odyssey
7  Bvlgari Octo
8  Aegir
9  Audemars Piguet Royal Oak Offshore""")

df = pd.read_csv(textfile, sep='\s\s+', engine='python')

print("Input dataframe...\n")
print(df.to_markdown())

listcomp = ['PILOT', 'SRP637', '103', 'Mako', 'Kontiki', 'SKX007', 'Odyssey','Octo', 'Royal Oak Offshore']
regex = f'{"|".join(listcomp)}'
df['model'] = df['brand'].str.extract(f'(?P<model>{regex})')
df['brand'] = df['brand'].str.replace(regex,'')
print("Output dataframe...\n")
print(df.to_markdown())
```

Outputs:

```
Input dataframe...

|    | brand                              |
|---:|:-----------------------------------|
|  0 | ARCHIMEDE PILOT                    |
|  1 | Seiko SRP637                       |
|  2 | Sinn 103                           |
|  3 | Orient Mako                        |
|  4 | Eterna Kontiki                     |
|  5 | Seiko SKX007                       |
|  6 | Boldr Odyssey                      |
|  7 | Bvlgari Octo                       |
|  8 | Aegir                              |
|  9 | Audemars Piguet Royal Oak Offshore |
Output dataframe...

|    | brand           | model              |
|---:|:----------------|:-------------------|
|  0 | ARCHIMEDE       | PILOT              |
|  1 | Seiko           | SRP637             |
|  2 | Sinn            | 103                |
|  3 | Orient          | Mako               |
|  4 | Eterna          | Kontiki            |
|  5 | Seiko           | SKX007             |
|  6 | Boldr           | Odyssey            |
|  7 | Bvlgari         | Octo               |
|  8 | Aegir           | nan                |
|  9 | Audemars Piguet | Royal Oak Offshore |
```

### Option 1:

Use pandas to first split on space using `.str.split`, then use `where` and `isin`:

```
listcomp = ['PILOT', 'SRP637', '103', 'Mako', 'Kontiki', 'SKX007', 'Odyssey','Octo']
df_out = df['brand'].str.split(' ', expand=True).set_axis(['brand', 'model'], axis=1, inplace=False)
df_out['model'] = df_out['model'].where(df_out['model'].isin(listcomp))
df_out
```

Output:

```
|    | brand     | model   |
|---:|:----------|:--------|
|  0 | ARCHIMEDE | PILOT   |
|  1 | Seiko     | SRP637  |
|  2 | Sinn      | 103     |
|  3 | Orient    | Mako    |
|  4 | Eterna    | Kontiki |
|  5 | Seiko     | SKX007  |
|  6 | Boldr     | Odyssey |
|  7 | Bvlgari   | Octo    |
|  8 | Aegir     | nan     |
```

### Option 2

Use .str.extract with named groups

```
listcomp = ['PILOT', 'SRP637', '103', 'Mako', 'Kontiki', 'SKX007', 'Odyssey','Octo']
regex = f'{"|".join(listcomp)}'
df['brand'].str.extract(f'(?P<brand>\w+)\s?(?P<model>{regex})?')
```

Output:

```
|    | brand     | model   |
|---:|:----------|:--------|
|  0 | ARCHIMEDE | PILOT   |
|  1 | Seiko     | SRP637  |
|  2 | Sinn      | 103     |
|  3 | Orient    | Mako    |
|  4 | Eterna    | Kontiki |
|  5 | Seiko     | SKX007  |
|  6 | Boldr     | Odyssey |
|  7 | Bvlgari   | Octo    |
|  8 | Aegir     | nan     |
```

### Option 3 (updated with changed question and data)

```
listcomp = ['PILOT', 'SRP637', '103', 'Mako', 'Kontiki', 'SKX007', 'Odyssey','Octo', 'Royal Oak Offshore']
regex = f'{"|".join(listcomp)}'
df['model'] = df['brand'].str.extract(f'(?P<model>{regex})')
df['brand'] = df['brand'].str.replace(regex,'')
df
```

Output:

```
|    | brand           | model              |
|---:|:----------------|:-------------------|
|  0 | ARCHIMEDE       | PILOT              |
|  1 | Seiko           | SRP637             |
|  2 | Sinn            | 103                |
|  3 | Orient          | Mako               |
|  4 | Eterna          | Kontiki            |
|  5 | Seiko           | SKX007             |
|  6 | Boldr           | Odyssey            |
|  7 | Bvlgari         | Octo               |
|  8 | Aegir           | nan                |
|  9 | Audemars Piguet | Royal Oak Offshore |
```

Comment: option number 1 got this error message - ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 3 elements, new values have 2 elements

Comment: option number 2 how I can retrieve model? option number 3 is wrong.

Comment: @MohammadNurdin Yes, Option 1 and Option 2 worked for your original data, Option 3 is probably the solution.

Comment: I already tried, model's column got NaN. you forgot to extract "Royal Oak Offshore" from the list

Comment: I didn't modify listcomp.  I just checked.  It works.

Comment: this is my list, ['PILOT', 'SRP637', '103', 'Mako', 'Kontiki', 'SKX007', 'Odyssey','Octo', 'Royal Oak Offshore']. I got model all NaN.

Comment: Would you copy my code as is and try it with your dataframe?

Comment: @MohammadNurdin See minimal complete verifiable example.... above.

Comment: What version fo pandas are you using... maybe a version issue.  I am on pandas 1.0.0.

Comment: I'd appreciate lifting the downvote if this works as expected.  Thanks.

Comment: it seems my model list causes NaN. how to fix this?

Comment: Can you produce an input that shows the NaN?  Modify your question with to generate that NaN by taking my MCVE example.   Maybe I can help.

Comment: Part of your problem is capialization.    `df['model'] = df['brand'].str.lower().str.extract(f'(?P<model>{regex})')` this works a little better.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want this:

```
df['model'] = df['brand'].apply(lambda x: x.split(' ')[1])
```

That takes every `brand` row, splits it into two pieces by the blank space, and takes the second element to be the new column.

Comment: so how I can compare with the list?

Comment: what do you want to compare? I'm not sure I understand. Your output is exactly taking the second word in `brand` as a new column. What does the comparison you have in mind do?

Comment: check my updated question. thats why the reason why I need to compare which one match with the list.